Printing a funnel on a resin printer without suction cupping
I'm trying to print a funnel similar to Anycubic Photon Resin Bottle Funnel Filter Holder. I know one of the big issues with this kind of printing is suction cupping, which printing the filter will lead to a huge one. The shape seems like it would print without any support, but I'm struggling with figuring out how to get this to print right. I have a Mars 3D Pro and am using Lychee to slice the models.
My thoughts are as follows:

Use some kind of raft, but I have no idea what kind would work to
prevent a suction cup.
Maybe put it at an angle and use supports? I'd rather not, but...
Use the default Lychee supports in full, probably medium or heavy due to the large size of the funnel.

It seems like this should be easy, just a single raft-type structure that will raise it up enough to prevent suction cups and be easily removable, but maybe I'm just oversimplifying the process.
What do I do? Thanks!

I'm not an expert, but what I have seen most of the time is printing at an angle (your #2). Why would you "rather not"?

Maybe I just need to accept that adding structure is something that is needed. I guess I'll give that a shot then.

The solution to suction cupping is to place the wide end flat on the built plate, and then to rotate it at 45 degrees. That way the leading edge is a slant, which pushes resin out of the way on the way down and lets it drain on the way up, while maintaining a small surface area.
Because you won't have any areas in contact with the FEP that is closed off on all sides suction cupping will be kept to a minimum.
Print using a raft, heavy supports for the widest part, especially the brim, medium supports as you taper towards the narrow end, highest support density on the ridge line lower density the further around the curve they go.

I'd suggest adding a little notch like this:

to prevent air or resin from getting trapped. That way you don't have to add rafts if you don't want to.

I suppose that is a way to do it. I have another similar thing that I'd rather not put a notch in like that, but I'm starting to just accept that to print in resin this kind of thing notches need to be included...

yes... that or a raft or supports or drill a hole in your printbed. :)
